# Vue - Modal editar me auto actualiza el item sin darle a guardar

Tags: vue.js

estoy teniendo un problea a la hora de editar un **item**  de mi lista, y es que cuando le doy a editar y empiezo a modificarlo, la lista original se va cambiando automaticamente.. sin darle a guardar.

Tengo un modal que se le pasa por prop el **item que tiene que editar** .

Este es mi componente principal, la **lista**:

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-card v-show="showList" class="mx-auto" max-width="800">
    <v-list flat subheader three-line>
      <v-subheader>
        Lista de Cosas
        <v-btn fab dark color="indigo" x-large style="margin-left: 80%;" @click="show.createModal = true">
          <v-icon dark> mdi-plus </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-subheader>

      <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItems" multiple active-class="">
        <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.title+index" >
          <item @deleteItem="deleteItem" @editItem="editItem" :item="item" :index="index"></item>
        </div>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card> 

  <modalCreateItem :showModal="show.createModal" @exitModal="show.createModal = false"></modalCreateItem>
  <modalDeleteItem :showModal="itemToDeleteIndex!= null" :index="itemToDeleteIndex" @exitModal="exitModal()" @deleteItem="deleteItem()"></modalDeleteItem>
  <modalEditItem :showModal="show.editModal" :data="dataToEdit"  @exitModal="exitModal()"></modalEditItem>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import DialogCreateTask from '../Dialogs/DialogCreateTask';
import DialogDeleteTask from '../Dialogs/DialogDeleteTask';
import ListItemComponent from "./ListItemComponent";
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import DialogEditTask from '../Dialogs/DialogEditTask';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItems: [],
      itemToDeleteIndex:null,
      dataToEdit:null,
      show:{
        list:false,
        createModal:false,
        deleteModal:false,
        editModal:false
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    item: ListItemComponent,
    modalCreateItem:DialogCreateTask,
    modalDeleteItem:DialogDeleteTask,
    modalEditItem:DialogEditTask
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.showList = true;
    this.$store.commit('task/examples');
  },
  methods: {
    deleteItem(data){
      this.itemToDeleteIndex = data.index;
    },
    editItem(data){
      console.log('Abrir modal edicion');
      console.log('Data = ',data);
      this.show.editModal = true;
      this.dataToEdit=data;
      
    },
    exitModal(){
      console.log('exitModal (parent)');
      this.itemToDeleteIndex = null
      this.dataToEdit = null;
      this.show.deleteModal = false;
      this.show.editModal = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('task',{
      items: state => state.items
    })
  },
};
</script>
```

Tengo un data de mi componente : `dataToEdit`, que contiene la info del item a editar y el indice que ocupa en la lista. Una vez se lo paso a mi **Modal de Edicion** se abre este:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="display" persistent max-width="600px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class="text-h5">Editar Task</span>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container v-if ="data">
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-alert dense type="warning" v-show="this.alert.show">
                {{ this.alert.message }}
              </v-alert>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-text-field
                label="Titulo*"
                required
                v-model="data.item.title"
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-textarea
                label="Descripcion"
                v-model="data.item.description"
              ></v-textarea>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="exitModal()"> Close </v-btn>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text> Save </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    alert: {
      show: false,
      message: null,
    },
    dataBackup: null,
  }),
  props: ["showModal", "data"],
  computed: {
    display() {
      return this.$props.showModal;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    exitModal() {

      console.log("editModal => exitModal()");
      this.$emit("exitModal", true);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("props");
    console.log(this.$props);
  },
  watch: {
    data: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      // watch it
      // console.log("Prop changed: ", newVal, " | was: ", oldVal);
      if(newVal){
        this.dataBackup =  Object.assign({}, newVal);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Me detecta bien cada componente, es decir, me rellena la descripcion y el titulo correctamente cada vez que le doy a un item diferente, pero al cambiar por ejemplo el titulo, veo en la lista que se van refrescando el valor. Yo tengo dos botones, uno para guardar : que debe hacer eso, guardarlo (pero no antes) y el de atras, con el que debe desechar los cambios.

Pero no se porque hace esto.

**Nota:**
No tengo backend, quiero que sea todo local.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya he encontrado una solucion,
mi funcion **editItem()** del component  **ListComponent** el valor de la prop que sirve para saber que item tengo que editar, antes de setearlo hago lo siguiente :

```
   editItem(data){
      console.log('Abrir modal edicion');
      console.log('Data = ',data);
      this.show.editModal = true;
      //Esto hace que pierda el databinding
      this.dataToEdit=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      
    },
```